# How to safely upgrade Deja Dup on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, deja-dup

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04, with Deja Dup 22.0.

I would like to update Deja Dup to later releases so I can utilize the integrity check feature for the backups, as suggested here: ([How can I test the integrity of a backup made with Backup (Deja Dup)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99739/how-can-i-test-the-integrity-of-a-backup-made-with-backup-deja-dup?newreg=936b696ee7454cd09bc3a91bce5627df))

However `apt-get install --only-upgrade deja-dup`, states that I already have the newest version (22.0). What is the optimal way to safely upgrade Deja Dup to newer versions on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=deja-dup, 22.0 is the current version available for precise. All the newer ones are for newer releases. The [Launchpad page for Deja Dup](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup) says that there are two options: the official repository, or a daily PPA. I don't recommend a daily PPA for something critical like a backup utility. However, it looks like the daily PPA hasn't been updated in *months*, so it might be missing bug fixes, or it might be perfectly stable. You can perhaps get [the source package for trusty](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/deja-dup) and the relevant dependencies and build your own package. Unfortunately that does not look like an easy task, since v30.0 depends on a much newer version of `libc6`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the question I linked, the user was on 11.10, which made it seem like there was a safe and easy way to upgrade Deja Dup to newer versions. I'll look into another way of testing the the backups for Deja Dup.